# making a triangle diagram however iam unable to make make the final pattern

Tags: c++

Trying to make the following pattern and have tried to make several changes; however, I'm unable to replicate the exact same pattern can someone help? I've also attached the picture of the pattern!

[image]

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

void triangle(int n) 
{ 
    
    int k = 2 * n - 2; 
  
  
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
  
       
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) 
            cout << " "; 
  
       
        k = k - 1; 
  
      
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) { 
             
            cout << " "<<i; 
        } 
  
        
        cout << endl; 
    } 
} 
  

int main() 
{ 
    int n = 5; 
    triangle(n); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few errors in your logic. In the 2nd nested for loop the loop should start as-

```
for(j=1; j<=i; j++) //you used j=0 here
     cout<<" "<<j; //you used i here
```

and coming out of the loop you need to print an extra one here.
so after this loop use

```
cout<<" 1"<<endl  // it is for the extra 1 at the end of each line;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are minor issues in your code

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

void triangle(int n) 
{ 
    
    int k = 2 * n - 2; 
  
  
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
  
       
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) 
            cout << " "; 
  
       
        k = k - 1; 
  
      
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) { //you started loop from j=0 
             
            cout << " "<<j;            //you need to print 'j' and not 'i' 
        } 
  
        cout<<" 1"<<endl;             // for the trailing '1' in every line
    } 
} 
  

int main() 
{ 
    int n = 5; 
    triangle(n); 
    return 0; 
}
```

I have commented the changes in the code.